# Subtraction method as variable

Tags: r

Is it possible to assign subtraction (or division) in R as object and to call it? So that following example produce `-1`

```
a <- 1
b <- 2

method <- "-"
a method b
# Wanted result -1

method <- "/"
a method b
# Wanted result 0.5
```

**Why I need this**
I want to set function parameter to either `-` or `/`. Something like that:

```
dummyF <- function(a, b, method) {
    a get(method) b
}
```

Comment: Would `dummyF <- function(a, b, method) { txt = paste(a, method, b); eval(parse(text=txt)) }` suit your needs?

Comment: If you only have two possible methods, you might want to hard-code them and then make selection a TRUE/FALSE option, like `function(a, b, do_plus) (if (do_plus) \`+\` else \`/\`)(a, b)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use backticks and then call the function using normal function notation, not infix notation:

```
foo <- `-`
foo(1,2)
```

An example with them in a list:

```
l <- list(add = `+`,subtract = `-`)
> l[["add"]](1,2)
[1] 3
> l[["subtract"]](1,2)
[1] -1
```

Answer (score 6):

We can use `do.call`

```
method <- "-"
do.call(method, list(a,b))
#[1] -1

method <- "/"
do.call(method, list(a,b))
#[1] 0.5
```