# How to supply (logical) operators as arguments to function

Tags: r, function, arguments, operators

Is it possible to supply logical (or arithmetic) operators as arguments to R functions. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36699777/subtraction-method-as-variable) SO question that share the theme.

```
f1 <- function(a, b) a>b
```

Then

```
> f1(1,2)
[1] FALSE
```

How can I implement an operator that allows me to for instance change the function test, e.g.

```
f2 <- function(a, b, operator = c('<', '>', '==')) { ... }
```

Then I would like

```
> f2(1, 2, '<')
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtraction method as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36699777/subtraction-method-as-variable)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In R, all operators are functions. So, you only need to get the operator function and call it.

```
f2 <- function(a, b, operator) getFunction(operator)(a, b)
f2(1, 2, '<')
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Ah did not knew of `getFunction`. It seems a little more concise than the eval(parse()) approach. And more safe perhaps ?

Comment: @user3375672 "If the answer is `parse()` you should usually rethink the question." [(fortune 106)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fortunes/vignettes/fortunes.pdf)

Comment: see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse)

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option:

```
foo <- function(a, b, operator) {
   f <- match.fun(match.arg(operator, choices = c('<', '>', '=='))) 
   f(a,b) 
}

foo(1,2, ">")
#[1] FALSE
foo(1,2, "==")
#[1] FALSE
foo(1,2, "+")
# Show Traceback
# 
# Rerun with Debug
# Error in match.arg(operator, choices = c("<", ">", "==")) : 
#  'arg' should be one of “<”, “>”, “==”
```

Using `match.arg` allows you to restrict it to certain functions. `match.fun` then gets the actual function.

In case you don't need the restriction to certain inputs, you can skip the `match.arg` and just use `match.fun`.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use `eval(parse(...))` methodology, i.e.

```
f1 <- function(a, b, op){
  eval(parse(text = paste0(a, op, b)))
}

f1(1, 2, '<')
#[1] TRUE
f1(3, 3, '==')
#[1] TRUE
f1(3, 4, '==')
#[1] FALSE
```